# String replace, strip one value from another in LINQ query

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, linq

I have the following controller method where the AppVersion contains the exact value in Name, with some other string, like Name: Some Application, AppVersion: Some Application - Production.  I need to strip the value of Name from the value of AppVersion.  I tried to search but not sure what I am looking for.

```
public IActionResult GetByAppId(string Id)
{
    return new JsonResult(_db.Applications
        .Select(a => new
        {
            a.Id,
            a.AppId,
            a.Name,
            a.AppVersion
        })
        .Where(a => a.Id == Id)
        .SingleOrDefault()
    );
}
```

Examples of current output:

```
Name: Employee Recognition
AppVersion: Employee Recognition - Acceptance

Name: Content Delivery Platform (CDP)
AppVersion:  Content Delivery Platform (CDP) - pod 2 - Production
```

Comment: Why the <sql> tag?

Comment: Some example current output and desired output would be good.

Comment: Regular Expressions is what you should look up.

Comment: Can you please provide at least 2 example-values for AppVersion?

Comment: @LewsTherin I did provide that in my question.  Will break it out.

Comment: Don't mix the query with the `JsonResult` call. Store the result in a variable and modify the properties.

Comment: This is logic I would put inside the `Application` entity (if possible), perhaps a new property such as `FormattedAppVersion` to avoid duplicating it in multiple queries.

Comment: @ConnieDeCinkoCS you didn't provide any examples in your question, just a confusing description. What do you expect the *output* to look like? In any case, `SingleOrDefault()` returns a single object. Store that in a variable and then modify the string properties

Comment: What is your expected output? You want the ap version without the name or the part after the first `-`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can replace it with nothing:

```
public IActionResult GetByAppId(string Id)
{
    return new JsonResult(_db.Applications
        .Select(a => new
        {
            a.Id,
            a.AppId,
            a.Name,
            AppVersion = a.AppVersion.Replace(a.Name, "")
        })
        .Where(a => a.Id == Id)
        .SingleOrDefault()
    );
}
```

Comment: Thanks!  Exactly what I was looking for, just could not quite get the syntax right.